# Using eval in PHP

Tags: php, include, external

I have a file "xxx.php" which has HTML and PHP code in it. When I use `include("xxx.php");` it's fine and it works as expected. But I am developing a system where I cannot use include but I can use `file_get_contents()`.

The problem is that if I do echo file_get_contents("xxx.php") it shows the entire source code whithout interpreting the PHP.

So I did a lot of research and I discovered that I could use `eval()` to run the PHP code. The problem is that "xxx.php" has php and HTML code. I tried:

```
eval(file_get_contents("xxx.php"));
```

But the HTML is not shown. Example of the xxx.php:

```
<?php
echo "HELLO";
?>
<b>HELLO BOLD</b>
<?php
echo "BYE";
?>
```

The problem is that the eval does not show any HELLO!

Comment: Can you please elaborate on why your system cannot use include?

Comment: there are all kinds of things wrong with this.. where to begin...

Comment: never seen a system that doesnt have include allowed, even on shared hosting.

Comment: it's a CMS that my company developed to all the clients. We have over 600 websites developed and we had MANY invasions recently and it's sure because include(). So we blocked include and it solved a LOT many os our problems. But we need someway to import and exec php inside other files cause we can parse it before use the file_get_contents(). Our CMS is very sophisticated and we won 3 national prizes last year, but it's vulnerable to some specific attacks. The manual of CMS is in http://www.sitepor500.com.br/manual so you can see how it looks like.

Comment: use ajax instead `file_get_content` to get the `xxx.php` page

Comment: @Glauco ... you are using eval to make your site more secure... that's kinda backwards. I suggest you solve the root problem instead of enabling countless others.

Comment: [TDWTF](http://www.thedailywtf.com/) anyone?

Comment: `include()` is not an attack vector unless you're loading files from external sites, or allowing user-defined data into the include call. e.g. `include($_GET['hack_me_please']);`. A "sophisticated" cms would not be vulnerable to such simplistic attacks. Any code which could get in via include() will STILL be able to get in via `eval(file_get_contents())` so you've accomplished NOTHING.

Comment: Look Sirs, I use eval with file_get_contents cause I can parse the xxx.php and check if it uses some custom function that I want to block in my apache like preg_match and preg_replace. I need to detect this functions and remove them from the file PRIOR executing it. Maybe I could solve this problem if you could tell me someway I could block some specific functions in  my server. Note: I have a VPS so I have some privileges but not too much.

Comment: @Glauco: There are many ways to bypass such a blacklist. (Heard of [variable functions](http://php.net/manual/en/functions.variable-functions.php)?) You need to figure out how hackers are managing to upload malicious files to your server and patch those holes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`echo file_get_contents()` showing the code is to be expected. f_g_c() does not EXECUTE anything it retrieves. It simply slurps the bytes from the disk and returns them as a string. That's why you need `eval()`.

As well, when you `eval()` code, you should **NOT** include the `<?php` delimiters. e.g.

```
php > eval('2+2;'); // no return, no echo, so no output
php > eval('echo 2+2;');
4
php > eval('<?php echo 2+2;');
PHP Parse error:  syntax error, unexpected '<' in php shell code(1) : eval()'d code on line 1
php >
```

---

comment follow up:

just treat anything you feed to eval as if it was a normal PHP script that just so happens to have a `<?php` opening tag magically applied to it:

```
php > eval('?> foo <?php echo 2+2;');
 foo 4
```

If you exit PHP mode as the first thing in the eval block, eval will just treat that text as normal output, just like a full-blown PHP script would

Comment: Great! I can remove the <?php and ?> with REGEX but it the code has html? How does the eval worki? To me it looks like it stops the execution at that point and does not continue to exec the rest.

Answer (score 2):

Prepend `"?>\n"` to the PHP code (to go into HTML mode) before evaling it:

```
eval("?>\n" . file_get_contents("xxx.php"));
```

And fix the security problems in your CMS so you won't have to resort to such drastic measures to dodge the script kiddies' attacks.

Comment: Look Sirs, I use eval with file_get_contents cause I can parse the xxx.php and check if it uses some custom function that I want to block in my apache like preg_match and preg_replace. I need to detect this functions and remove them from the file PRIOR executing it. Maybe I could solve this problem if you could tell me someway I could block some specific functions in  my server. Note: I have a VPS so I have some privileges but not too much.

Comment: to disable functions see [here](http://www.php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.disable-functions)

Comment: You are great! Thank you much @Orangepill ! i WILL disable that functions so my cms will be more secure ANd I wil be able to keep using include AS you all proved me is much better than using eval with file_get_contents.

Answer (score 0):

For the love of `<insert diety here>` don't do this.... but your code is failing because you need to remove the `<?php` from the top of the eval.

Eval expects php code so the `<?php` and `?>` as assumed.

What you are doing here is not securing your site but making it easier to hack.

Comment: Ok Sir @Orangepill . But my xxx.php may have html and the eval() breaks it in a such way that it does not display it at all.

Comment: then detect and trim the leading <?php and the trailing ?> from the string that file_get_contents produces.